# jQuery - Problems with this.text()

Tags: jquery, if-statement, this

I don't know how to describe my problem properly but I think I just need a little push into the right direction. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhKA9/1/) that hopefully explains my problem. I have a link list with an onClick event handler. The respective function should pass the text of the listitem to a new function which compares the string to another string. In my understanding, the first list item (test) should alert "Cool" (since the strings exactly match), but it won't.

Any ideas?

I know that this would work if I use `e.target.name` instead of `$(this).text()`, but I need to pass the link text and not an attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$.trim` utility function:

```
clickFunc($.trim($(this).text()));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cncfA/

Answer (score 2):

Filter down to the anchor tag.

```
$('a', this).text();
```

Otherwise you may get empty text nodes from the li.

http://jsfiddle.net/vhKA9/2/

Comment: works perfectly, thanks. still don't know how an if comparison could fail when both strings are the same...

Comment: That's just it, they aren't the same. One has extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

your li doesn't have text..  they contain <a> that have text.. try:

```
$(this).find('a').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you were binding the `click` event to the `li` elements in your list, as opposed to the `a` elements.  When you change it to bind to the `a`, it works as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/WdVbk/

If you really want the `click` event on the `li` elements, change how you get the text to send to the function:

`clickFunc($(this).find('a').text());`

http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/FVSuz/

Edit: Yeah, there are some `console.log` statements in my Fiddles, if you're in IE it might break.

Comment: Which version did you go with?